# Pandas: Filtering row with multiple string conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that has a column that looks like this:

```
NAME
ZZKIDS
ZZZKIDS
ZZZANTHONY
```

To filter the rows, I know I can use this:

```
df[~df.NAME.str.contains("ZZ")]
```

Is there a way to add the other "ZZZ" along with "ZZ"?

Comment: `df[~df.NAME.str.contains("ZZ|ZZZ")]`?

Comment: Yes, the string can be a regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
df[~df.NAME.str.contains('Z{2,}')]
```

`'Z{2,}'` means 2 or more occurences of `Z`

Comment: Thanks man. Quick question, would it filter out something like "ZACKZ" since there are 2 or more occurences of Z?

Comment: No, the way I did it would only be looking for consecutive `Z`s. If you wanted to filter out any values where there are more than 2 Z's, regardless of whether they are consecutive, you could use: `df[df.NAME.str.count('Z') > 2]` for example

Comment: @sacul might be the OP only wants `df[~df.NAME.str.startswith('ZZ')]` here... (given the examples...) also - if a string contains at least 2 consecutive Z's... just a check for ZZ is enough as 3 consecutive Z's will also match just two consecutive Z's anyway...